# Is it possible to create your own server on the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-3

Is it possible to create your own server on the Xbox 360?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have just added dedicated servers for the consoles. You need to pay though !
Its called rent-a-server.

(this is for anyone still interested to know)

Answer (score 3):

No. There is nothing in place (unless I've missed it) to host a game of BF3 on your own server. This is for the best as hosting one's own server opens up the potential for great abuse.

Comment: So there is no way I can play 1v1 ? :(

Comment: ...why would you want to?

Answer (score 2):

You can find an empty server sometimes using the server browser, but you need to have 6 players in the server for the match to begin.

Comment: I think he wanted to play a 1v1 for some reason. Maybe he can get 4 people to watch? =)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make your own servers hosted from your local xbox, the reason for this and the six player minimum is because of cheaters. A lot of people stat pad, or find methods of getting points quickly and effortlessly to rank up. It was a massive problem in Battlefield 2 and is still a problem in BF3. EA claims they went through and wiped accounts that showed signs of cheating, but I still see players with rediculous ranks, so they failed.